# The best way to execute task in background

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I would like to know the best way to execute a background task every hour. It consists of synchronizing an ftp directory and displaying on a notification if there have been changes. I thought it was done with services but I heard about JobScheduler or WorkManager. Furthermore the application will run on a Samsung device with oneui which can sometimes kill the process? Is it supported with certain solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger particular time means exact time. Then go with Alarm Manager.and if timing is not on your priority then Go with Work Manager

Alarm manager on Samsung oneUI is worked perfectly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ok cool I assume that the work manager consumes less battery then? I’m looking for the most reliable, with work manager the timing is just not precise right ? And is it working well on Samsung devices too?

Comment: Yes, it working well on all device. And its consume leass resources and upto date way to do periodically tasks in background. Mark as accepted if information is useful